# Microsoft learning support for VS2010

Tags: wpf

OK, I am a big fan of WPF, and while it is large area to fully understand, Microsoft has been great in posting loads of training video at http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx

However with the release of 2010 it all seams to have gone very quiet. I expected a lot of the support to be updated for 2010 and I also expected a lot of new videos on the best way to use the new features in 2010. Currently I find myself working through videos based on 2008 (or even 2005) and trying to apply them to 2010. Don't get me wrong it not that I mind doing this, it just that I fear I may be learning methods which have better or different solutions in 2010.

It is just me expecting too much of Microsoft, or have I missed out on a new website?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to actual features, there is not much new in the WPF designer of VS2010 (except maybe the WYSIWYG databinding editor). Also WPF 4.0 does not contain any really signifcant new APIs (except maybe the VisualStateManager). [Here is a complete list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx). So you should be perfectly fine with those 2005/2008 videos.

Comment: I agree with bitbonk, nothing much has changed in WPF, the basic concepts are still all the same, there's just a few new features. See [What's New in WPF Version 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx) for a full list. This will help you identify areas where you can read beyond what the 2008 training materials provide. (@bitbonk, feel free to include that link in your answer if you think it's relevant)